# Retrieving values from multidimensional arrays

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array something like this:

```
   int[,] multiDimensionalArray2 = { { 1, 2 }, { 4, 5 } };
```

if I want to retrieve 1 and 2 and feed them into this:

```
int a;
int b;
```

How do I do it?

Is it something like this:

```
multiDimensionalArray2[0,0]
```

What if I wanted to put more numbers in the same form  e.g. `{ { 2, 1 }, { 4, 1 } };`, in the same form as above. Would it be something like this:

```
   int[,] multiDimensionalArray2 = { { 1, 2 }, { 4, 5 } },{ { 2, 1 }, { 4, 1 } };
```

To retrieve the second set would I do this, multiDimensionalArray2[1,1]

Comment: have you tried the code you have suggested? That would be the easiest way to find out if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´re close, to retrieve the first numbers try this

```
        var a = multiDimensionalArray2[0, 0]; // x == 1
        var b = multiDimensionalArray2[0, 1]; // x == 2
```

Did you give it a try and it didn´t work? You´ll notice that SO users will encourage you to try-and-error first. Come back when you hit a wall :)

Answer (score 0):

Double dimention arrays are stored like this (picture it in your mind) as per your example

```
Row0  Row1 
1       2
4       5
2       1
4       1
```

Now follow what Dominik suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multi dimensional array like the one you gave,

```
int[,] multiDimensionalArray2 = { { 1, 2 }, { 4, 5 }, { 2, 1 }, { 4, 1 } };
```

We want to get the index of the number 5. To do this we need two indexes, **[a,b]**

Index **a** is the index of the "group of numbers" that you want to get.
First look at which group it is in. The first group (index 0) contains 1 and 2, the second group (index 1) contains 4 and 5.
Therefore **a** = 1.

Index **b** is the index of the "position within the group" that you want to get.
In the group **{4, 5}**, the number 5 is the first item (index 0). Therfore **b** = 0.

This means that the number 5 can be found at **multiDimensionalArray2[1,0]**

Answer (score -1):

Chao, I search documents in MSDN site for you, you should give it a try if you want.

Here is how I see on MSDN

List< > > 
Dictionary<>

I guess it works for your problem too, it can dynamically grow longer or shorter. they say using generic classes might be better, I am not sure about whether it ought to be faster or not though.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't really help answer the question whatsoever.